# problem exporting a table widget as an excel files

Tags: pyqt5

I need exporting a table widget (headers included) as an excel file but I receive an error:

`File "/Users/manuelzompetta/OneDrive/Programmazione/PycharmProjects/ProjectX/Int_PX_1.py", line 434, in tb1_2_Export2
    Func_PX_1.save_wtable_to_xls(self.table_View_1, filename)
  File "/Users/manuelzompetta/OneDrive/Programmazione/PycharmProjects/ProjectX/Func_PX_1.py", line 94, in save_wtable_to_xls
    sheet.write(r + 1, c + 1, text)
  File "/Users/manuelzompetta/.conda/envs/PycharmProjects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlwt/Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "/Users/manuelzompetta/.conda/envs/PycharmProjects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 260, in write
    raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))
Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QVariant'>`

I've implemented two files: one for the GUI >> Int_PX_1 and one containing exporting function >> Functions_PX_1

Here is Int_PX_1 calling the function:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def tb1_2_Export2(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Esporta Analisi", "Output.xlsx",
                                              "Excel Files (*.xlsx)", options=options)
    Func_PX_1.save_wtable_to_xls(self.table_View_1, filename)

    print('tb21_Export2')
```

Here's the exporting function:

```
def save_wtable_to_xls(table, filename):
   wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
   sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
   style = xlwt.XFStyle()
   font = xlwt.Font()
   font.bold = True
   style.font = font
   model = table.model()
    for c in range(model.columnCount()):
        text = model.headerData(c, Int_PX_1.Qt.Horizontal)
        sheet.write(0, c + 1, text, style=style)

    for r in range(model.rowCount()):
        text = model.headerData(r, Int_PX_1.Qt.Vertical)
        sheet.write(r + 1, 0, text, style=style)

    for c in range(model.columnCount()):
        for r in range(model.rowCount()):
            text = model.data(model.index(r, c))
            sheet.write(r + 1, c + 1, text)
    wbk.save(filename)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: I use python 3. Please check the comments to the other previous task I commented :)

Comment: whats is your pyqt5 version?

Comment: try change `text = model.data(model.index(r, c))` to `text = model.data(model.index(r, c)).toPyObject()` or `text = model.data(model.index(r, c)).toString()`

Comment: yes my version is pyqt5

Comment: I think you did not understand me, in my case I have PyQt5 5.11.3 what is your version of PyQt5?

Comment: @eyllanesc, ah sorry my version is 5.9.2, python 3.6.7 in an anaconda environment. Do you have an email or any contact? If you are interested maybe we could collaborate.